# Id item not incremented in href attribute

Tags: jsp, tags, jstl, href

I have a jsp page that displays a table of items, the first column of each line is a link to another page for displaying details and editing the item, my problem is that the link generation in href attribute is not correct, it does not contain the id of the item even if the id is displayed well in the table, the id in the href link is always at zero.

```
<table class="footable no-paging table-striped" data-page-navigation=".pagination">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="40%" data-sort-initial="descending">Identifiant</th>
            <th width="60%" data-sort-ignore="true">Type</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody> 
        <c:forEach items="${myList}" var="item">                    
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <c:url value="/format/edit/details" var="editURL" >
                        <c:param name="idF" value="${item.idItem}" />
                    </c:url> 
                    <a href="${editURL}" >
                        <i><c:out value="${item.idItem}" /></i>
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td><c:out value="${formation.type}" /></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot class="hide-if-no-paging">
        <tr>
            <td width="20%" />
            <td width="79%" colspan="5">
                <div class="pagination pagination-centered"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

the content of my table is like below:

```
--------------------------------------------
|  Id                 |  Type              |
--------------------------------------------
|   1                 |  type1             |
----------------------|--------------------|
|   2                 |  type2             |
--------------------------------------------
```

the link generated for the first line : /format/edit/details?idF=0
it's the same link generated for the second line :  /format/edit/details?idF=0

my object "myList" is a List, and the "idItem" is of type Long (even when i'have changed it to String i get the same result)

why the idF is not incremented and always at zero? is it the scope of the variable which must be specified? any idea?

Comment: maybe c:param is expecting a value that comes from the http request, not from the c:forEach loop

Comment: do you have another idea how to implement this?

Comment: how about getting rid of the whole c:url block and assembling the url link manually?

Comment: yes done manually, but still the tag url is not yet operational i didn't find a documentation about that case, anyway the problem is considered solved, thank you for your replies Leo